# P-value normal test for multiple rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statistics

I got the following simple code to calculate normality over an array:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("directory\file.xlsx")
import numpy as np
x=df.iloc[:,1:].values.flatten()
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.stats import normaltest 
stats.normaltest(x,axis=None)
```

This gives me nicely a p-value and a statistic.
The only thing I want right now is to:

**Add 2 columns** in the file with this **p** value and **statistic** and if i have multiple rows, do it for all the rows (calculate p value & statistic for each row and add 2 columns with these values in it).

Can someone help?

Comment: If you want to add a column you may do this: `df['name_of_new_colum'] = value_to_store`

Comment: thanks, but how can I put the p value in one column and the statistic in the other. Seems I can't split them up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate row-wise `normaltest`, you should not `flatten` your data in `x` and use `axis=1` such as

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(105).reshape(5,21)) # to generate data
# calculate normaltest row-wise without the first column like you
df['stat'] ,df['p'] = stats.normaltest(df.iloc[:,1:],axis=1)
```

Then `df` contains two columns 'stat' and 'p' with the values your are looking for IIUC.

Note: to be able to perform `normaltest`, you need at least 8 values (according to what I experienced) so you need at least 8 columns in `df.iloc[:,1:]` otherwise it will raise an error. And even, it would be better to have more than 20 values in each row.